# Using html input size/maxlength with bootstrap's form-control

Tags: css, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, input

I came across an interesting issue when trying to use html5's form size/maxlength and bootstrap.

The size is overridden by boostrap's .form-control class, but removing it causes the input to lose its styling.

Code pen : http://codepen.io/rkhayat/pen/JoeBqx

Thanks

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Phone</p><input class="form-control" id="inputPhone" maxlength=
        "3" name="phone" required="required" size="3" title="" type="tel"
        value="">
    </div>
</div><!--with form-control-->

<div class="container">
    <p>Notice that removing form-control loses ALL styling, but keeps the
    size from html size input</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="form-group">
        <p>Phone</p><input id="inputPhone" maxlength="3" name="phone"
        required="required" size="3" title="" type="tel" value="">
    </div>
</div><!--without form-control-->
```

Edit: Researching I have found this http://getbootstrap.com/css/#column-sizing

Implemented bootstrap's recommended fix, feels like a hack.

```
  <div class="col-xs-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <p>Phone</p>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" value="" size="3" maxlength="3" required="required" title="">
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" value="" size="3" maxlength="3" required="required" title="">
                </div>


                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" value="" size="4" maxlength="4" required="required" title="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: If you want to control the width of input element then you could use Bootstrap's col-* or you can use inline styles.

Comment: thanks @web2tips, I did that with the updated codepen but it feels "hacky"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** This question has been viewed a lot, here's a blog post I wrote about it!
http://blog.dnwebdev.com/index.php/2015/07/28/my-bootstrap-toolbelt-phone-number-input/

Fixed it with the following if anyone is interested. Thank you @web2tips for your input. (Refer to question for html)

```
.phone-number .col-xs-3::after{
 content: "-";
 position:absolute;
 right: 5px;
 color: black;
 border: 0px solid;
 top: 5px;
}

.phone-number .col-xs-4{
 width:25%;
}

.phone-number .col-xs-3, .phone-number .col-xs-4{
padding-left:0;
}
```

It's a shame that bootstrap's .form-control has width built in though.

Answer (score 0):

I use am using cols to size width of lots of form elements (particularly whole `form-group`s). I just call them `class="skinny"` and then add:

```
.skinny{
padding-left:0;
}
```

Works fine for me so far. have not tried for maxlength but this solve my major layout headache!