# How to size the first text field in Bootstrap input group?

Tags: html, css, forms, bootstrap-5

I am trying to have country code and phone number using Bootstrap v5 input group using the following code but it's not working.

[image: the output am getting]

I want it to be in the following format by adjusting its width. Is it possible?

[image: expected output]

```css
.phone-code {
  width: 63px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="tel" class="form-control mb-2 phone-code" id="" placeholder="" value="+971">
  <input type="tel" class="form-control mb-2" id="phone-formatted" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
</div>
```

Comment: You have not accepted any provided answer.  If any helped you consider an upvote.  If any resolved your issue consider accepting that answer by clicking the green checkmark.
If none have helped resolve your issue please update your question as to why not so you might be provided with a proper great answer to your specific question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use max-width and add !important to overwright Bootstrap css

```css
.phone-code {
  max-width: 63px !important;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control mb-2 phone-code" id="" placeholder="" value="+971">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control mb-2" id="phone-formatted" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a row and set the column sizes.  Example

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder=".col-4">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container row mt-4 m-2">Sample with the wrap here using this kind of ugly option:</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="col-2">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control mb-2 phone-code" id="" placeholder="" value="+971">
  </div>
  <input type="tel" class="form-control mb-2" id="phone-formatted" placeholder="Enter your phone number">
</div>
```

Comment: @isherwood I just used the BootStrap 5 "getting started" CDN links for this version and V 5 for this or V 5.3 should not matter.; agree on the JS part for this one probably don't need that part. As for the CONTENT width - an input has no content until it well, has some and validation of 4 vs 40 characters is kind of out of scope as a "Bootstrap" solution.  So I illustrated (without custom CSS) ONE way to size an input.
Either way, I welcome the input here.

Comment: Yea, size is one challenge on forms with bootstrap without custom CSS ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29105846/125981  Similar to what I did: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67560645/125981 and the `w-50` does not work well IMHO for this.

Comment: I put a second with an ugly wrapper around the field - "kind of" still looks like the input but feel like a ugly option.